# How do i get the list of all Tables, Views, Stored procedures that are NOT added in a publication for replication

Tags: sql-server

How do i get the list of all **Tables**, **Views**, **Stored procedures** that are NOT added in a publication for `replication`?

Can you help me to make the stored Proc for that?I am new to Replication....Thanks

Comment: Pl add some more details...

Comment: I have 1 replication need to know which tables,views,SPs and UDFs are in Main DB but not published in replicated publication DB...

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
SELECT
      o.[object_id]
    , [object_name] = s.name + '.' + o.name
    , o.type_desc
FROM sys.sysobjects so WITH (NOLOCK)
JOIN sys.objects o WITH (NOLOCK) ON so.id = o.[object_id]
JOIN sys.schemas s WITH (NOLOCK) ON o.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
WHERE so.xtype IN ('P', 'V', 'U', 'TF', 'FN', 'IF')
    AND so.replinfo = 1
    AND o.is_published = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

For Snapshot and Transactional:

```
SELECT
    name 
FROM sysobjects WITH (NOLOCK) 
WHERE ((xtype = 'U') OR (xtype = 'V') OR (xtype = 'P')) AND 
    category <> 2 AND 
    name NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT object_name(OBJID) FROM sysarticles)
```

For Merge:

```
SELECT
    name 
FROM sysobjects WITH (NOLOCK) 
WHERE ((xtype = 'U') OR (xtype = 'V') OR (xtype = 'P')) AND 
    category <> 2 AND 
    name NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT object_name(OBJID) FROM sysmergearticles)
```